# Library file (.a) where the contents of the structure changes

Tags: c, embedded, structure, .a

I am creating an algorithm in C that is confidential and cannot be shared with external customers. So, I decided to go with creating a library (.a) file which compiles my algorithm and lets others use it without modifying it. It basically alters the data of a variable within a structure. Now, the structure as such is visible externally (The structure is defined in a separate header file which is included in my .c file) and is generated based on user's configuration. But the said variable is always present within the structure - only remaining data is changed based on user's configuration.

The problem is that if the structure is not exactly the one I used to create the library file, the code fails.
So is there a way to create a library file to modify the data inside a structure, if the structure itself is not available in the beginning?

Any help is greatly appreciated...

Comment: You are interested only in one data member of a structure? Then get the address of that variable in your confidential application and modify it's value.

Comment: @Babajan, I seem to have overlooked this one. thanks for the reply. Even I was thinking of implementing something similar and will mostlly go for this approach.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested only in one data member of a structure,Then get the address of that variable in your confidential application and modify it's value.

Answer (score 1):

Technically all structures you use must be character by character equal everywhere. If you have any difference between the same structure in two (or more) [translation units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) that will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

There are ways around that though, for example by using nested structures. For example you could create one structure to contain your private data, and then another structure whose *first* member is an instance of the first private structure.

For example something like this:

```
struct private_data
{
    // TODO: The private members here
};

struct public_data
{
    struct private_data private;
    // TODO: The public members here
};
```

This is in effect similar to inheritance of an object-oriented language. A pointer to the `public_data` structure can be cast as a pointer to the `private_data` structure and passed to the functions that need it.

To keep the private data, well, *private* you could use [opaque data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type) and [opaque pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer):

```
// Forward declaration of the actual private data
struct actual_private_data;

// The "public" private structure
struct private_data
{
    // Pointer to the actual private data
    struct actual_private_data *private;
};
```

---

It's important to note that this only works for the *private* data used for the library. If the public data structure contains data that needs to be accessed by the library as well, you might want to rename the `private_data` structure and put the common data there. Note that this common data ***must*** be in all variants of the structure, it can't be auto-generated differently than what is used in the library.

Comment: Hi @SomeProgrammerdude 

So, my actual data structure is 
typedef struct 
{
int val 1; //This is always there 
/* remaining might be absent based on user config */
int val2;
...
}data;


Now, the .c file used to generate the library contains a function of the sort:
void updateAlgo(data* edit1)
{
edit1->val1 += 1; //some math operation that i need to do
}

So, is there no way to create a library file for this? Note that I cannot modify the structure as that would require editing other sections of the generated source which I dont have access to.

Comment: @WIll void updateAlgo(data edit1) Here pass by value is done. Whatever math operation is done inside function will have no effect on outside world as return type is void.If you pass by address then you may consider void updateAlgo(int* val)

Comment: @babajan, You are right
I missed that in my comment but I am passing by reference only so that the same modified element can be used by other functions.